# Run background task with interval when app is terminated

Tags: ios, swift, background, notifications, push

I have implemented OneSignal push notifications in my iOS Swift app. I am sending a push notification from my server and I want the app, on receiving this, to perform an HTTP Get request to get data from my server. I want to check this data for new data and only show the notification to the user if any data is available. If this is not possible, then how can I run a background task every ten minutes even when the app is swiped away? Here is my code right now

```
override func didReceive(_ request: UNNotificationRequest, withContentHandler contentHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationContent) -> Void) {

    Alamofire.request("my-url", method: .get, parameters: my-parameters).reponseJSON {

        // Check for any new data
        if isNewData {
            // Send user a local notification

        } else {
            return
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Please make sure to search for your question before you ask, multiple similar questions has been asked before regarding this.